# how to run select mysql command on more than 10 millions and still increasing

Tags: mysql

How i can run this mysql select command faster on a table with more than 10 million records and still growing every second.

```
"SELECT 
    date,ip,time,messagetype,username,nasip,
    failurecode,callerid,authordata,cmd,groupname 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM " . $tableName . " 
      WHERE callerid NOT LIKE '10.%') AS T1 
WHERE date BETWEEN '" . $date_back . "' AND '" . $date . "' 
      AND callerid <> '-' 
ORDER BY time DESC"
```

current count of records in the table is 13267701

indexing is done on all the columns

Comment: why can't you do a count using only 1 select statement ? are there other conditions as well ? which you haven't provided in the question

Comment: I would advice you to use @Strawberry answer instead that one is better indexable..

Comment: Why are you using a subquery? And why are you using a variable to hold the table name?

Answer (score 3):

Edited to reflect dramatically altered question...

Doesn't this do the same thing:

```
SELECT date
     , ip
     , time
     , messagetype
     , username
     , nasip
     , failurecode
     , callerid
     , authordata
     , cmd
     , groupname 
  FROM $tableName 
 WHERE callerid NOT LIKE '10.%'
   AND date BETWEEN '$date_back' AND '$date'
   AND callerid <> '-' 
 ORDER 
    BY time DESC
```

?

An index on (callerid,date) might be useful.

Also, see about sql injection.

Comment: I think this will return the same result set as that of the OP.

Comment: Sorry i have pasted the wrong query i have edited my question @cdaiga